# Mathematica Vector Integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector

I am trying to symbolically integrate this function:

$$
\int\mathrm dY\exp\left[\dfrac{-(Y-Y_0)\cdot\Sigma_l^{-1}\cdot(Y-Y_0)^\top-(Y-Z\cdot A^{-1})\cdot A\cdot\Sigma_d^{-1}\cdot A^\top\cdot(Y-Z\cdot A^{-1})^\top}{2}\right]
$$

where all the symbols are either vectors or matrices. Is it possible to do so on *Mathematica* and what would the syntax be? I'm sorry I am not very good with *Mathematica*. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at the command Integrate, there are many examples in the help file.

Comment: please show your initial code and function

Comment: How big are these vectors and matrices?

Comment: "... where all the symbols are either vectors or matrices": The symbols arrays of symbolic expressions (e.g. `Y = {x, y, z}`) or are they simple symbols representing vectors and matrices?

Comment: Well, which are vectors and which are matrices?  Perhaps lowercase letters, or boldface lower case letters for vectors will make your expression easier to read.  Thank you!